# Twitter takes users to /en/logged-in/ regardless of my settings

Tags: django, twitter, django-socialauth

I'm new to django-social-auth (please be gentle).  I've followed the directions pretty faithfully from here: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/README.rst

And, when setting up my Twitter API account, I've told Twitter that the redirect should be http://mysite.com/auth/logged-in/

Yet, when a user attempts to log-in with Twitter, they're taken to the Twitter Auth page and once the say Yes (or whatever), Twitter returns them to http://mysite.com/**en**/auth/logged-in/

In my settings.py file: I have these lines, which I thought were relevant

```
LOGIN_URL          = '/auth/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/auth/logged-in/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/auth/login-error/'
```

I have also disabled the django.core.context_processors.i18n context processor, just in case it was adding the language prefix.

What have I missed?

**UPDATE**

I have also now set these in my settings.py file:

```
USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = False
```

**UPDATE 2**

If it helps, I am running Django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 11.

Comment: This all feels like an I18N thing, but I'm confident I've disabled that context processor and specifically disabled it with the `USE_I18N=False`. Also, the language prefix doesn't appear on anything else.