# How to set a redirection url in a template?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using django-social-auth with Django 1.3.1 under Python 2.7.1.  I've been looking all over the place and I can't quite figure out how to use a custom redirection url for Twitter Authentication (or other providers).

I've read that I need to use this template tag in my html template to build the link to initiate the process:

```
{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}
```

This works relatively fine using the value in my settings.py file for the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` (although, see my question here: [Twitter takes users to /en/logged-in/ regardless of my settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406531/twitter-takes-users-to-en-logged-in-regardless-of-my-settings)) However, in this particular case, I need to redirect the user to a special url upon return.

I've read in other places that I need to pass the variable 'next' with my redirect value to the template or as a parameter on the twitter auth url.  How is this done?  My template is loaded as a HttpResponse, so, while I can certainly pass it template values, it isn't clear how I can use these in the above template tag.

Sorry for this basic question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I knew this was simple, and I feel a bit silly for even asking this one.  I guess I thought that django-social-auth had special provisions for doing this, but apparently, it's pretty manual.  Here's the solution for anyone else who ends up here:

In your view:
    ...
    from django.utils.http import urlquote
    ...

```
def my_view(request, ...):
  ...
  redirect_url = urlquote("http://your_required_redirect_url/")
  ...
  return render_to_response('your_template.html', { 'redirect_url' : redirect_url })
```

In 'your_template.html':

```
...
Login with <a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}?next={{ redirect_url }}">Twitter</a>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code:

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}?next={{ request.get_full_path }}">Login with Twitter</a>
```

this line of code makes redirect to the same page, you can even set it to your header.